# How to properly filter a df based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, filter, dplyr

I am trying to sample a dataset based on date class column,
quarterly for "Active" and monthly for "Inactive"

Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
  
## data ##
                 
df <- structure(list( 
             mes = c("01/01/2000", "01/02/2000", "01/03/2000", 
"01/04/2000", "01/05/2000", "01/06/2000", "01/07/2000", "01/08/2000", 
"01/09/2000", "01/10/2000", "01/11/2000", "01/12/2000"),
              status = c("Active", "Inactive",
                         "Active", "Inactive",
                         "Active", "Inactive",
                         "Active", "Active",
                         "Inactive", "Active",
                         "Inactive", "Active")),
             class = "data.frame",
             row.names = c(NA, -12L))

## setting date class for "mes" column ##

df$mes <- as.Date(df$mes,
                  format = "%d/%m/%Y")

## sampling ##

sample_df <- df %>%  
  dplyr :: filter(status %in% "Active",
                  status %in% "Inactive") %>%
            dplyr :: filter_if(status == "Active",
            month(mes) %in% c(3,6,9,12),
            month(mes) %in% c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

Console output:

```
Error in is_logical(.p) : objeto 'status' no encontrado
```

Is there any other library that I could use to accomplish this task?

Comment: See the solution provided by @akrun. For my own curiosity, could you please update your question and provide an expected output?

Comment: The error is due to incorrect syntax for `filter_if`. Not also that `across` is now recommended in place of `filter_if`, and that they are both used in the context of selecting column names, not variable values.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you wanted as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter quarterly months for `"Active"` status and all months for "Inactive" you could do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(mes)) %>%
  filter(status == "Active" & month %in% c(3,6,9,12) | 
         status == "Inactive" & month %in% 1:12)

#         mes   status month
#1 2000-02-01 Inactive     2
#2 2000-03-01   Active     3
#3 2000-04-01 Inactive     4
#4 2000-06-01 Inactive     6
#5 2000-09-01 Inactive     9
#6 2000-11-01 Inactive    11
#7 2000-12-01   Active    12
```

Since you want all months for "Inactive" status you can also do :

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(mes)) %>%
  filter(status == "Active" & month %in% c(3,6,9,12) | 
         status == "Inactive")
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr::filter`, if we use `,`, then it means `&`, instead, we need `|`.  Using `&` would result in `0 rows` because 'status' can't have both 'Active' and 'Inactive' at the same location

```
df %>%  
  dplyr::filter(status %in% "Active"| status %in% "Inactive") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(status == 'Active', month(mes) %in% c(3, 6, 9, 12))
```

Also, as we are using `%in%`, it can take a `vector` of values in the rhs of the operator `%in%` with `length` >= 1

```
 df %>%
    dplyr::filter(status %in% c("Active", "Inactive")) %>%      
    dplyr::filter(status == 'Active', month(mes) %in% c(3, 6, 9, 12))
```

---

In the OP's filter statement

```
...
 month(mes) %in% c(3,6,9,12),
        month(mes) %in% c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

implies both conditions should be true, but one of them is a subset of the another condition